# Margin before admin menu with Views admin pages

Tags: 7, views, theming

Screenshot shows the problem:
[image]
This margin appears on all **admin** pages which use Views on *Seven* theme and module *Administration menu*. As example, Drupal Commerce products list. Actually this is because of body class `.contextual-links-region`. I didn't find any issues about it. Can anybody comment it?

UPD: Problem disappeared after Drupal update to 7.8.

Comment: See http://drupal.org/node/1820296 for a thread on the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin_menu module adds a margin to the top of the page so it can sit there.  I suspect the toolbar module does the same thing which gives you the double margin.

Looking at your screenshot you're using 3 menu modules, which seems overkill to me.  Disable the toolbar module and you should be right.  The admin and admin_menu modules can happily coexist. You can also add custom items to either or both of these menus.

Personally I'd just go with the admin module.

Comment: I'm not using 3 menu modules. "Admin" can be turned off and nothing changes with my problem. And core module "Toolbox" is disabled. I don't know, why you could think that it's turned on.